# Angular7 + XHook gives ERROR TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: xmlhttprequest, angular7

I have a chrome plugin runnin Xhook which intercepts xhr requests.
This used to work with angular js. Now I am using an Angular 7 application And I am getting an error when I make following request

```
 this.http.get('someurl').subscribe((data: any) => {

 });
```

Which triggers `xhr.send(reqBody);` in the angular http.js library. The error is on the subscribe part, if I remove this the error is gone.

The error is the following:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at ZoneTask.scheduleTask [as scheduleFn] (zone.js:3238)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:410)
    at Object.onScheduleTask (zone.js:301)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (zone.js:404)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask (zone.js:238)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask (zone.js:261)
    at scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone (zone.js:1245)
    at zone.js:3276
    at _global.<computed>.proto.<computed> [as send] (zone.js:1569)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1726)
```

I am using this library: https://github.com/jpillora/xhook and the error is caused by line 478 `facade.send = function(body)` https://github.com/jpillora/xhook/blob/gh-pages/dist/xhook.js

I am thinking that: either angular tries to run the overridden function but something is not accessible because of zone.js, or I am missing certain properties, function in the object that overrides xhr?

If anyone has any information or solution on the subject that would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Nealv, did the error got resolved?

Comment: nope, still having the same issue